# how can I change the drawing and movement in snowflakes animation and making it more animated?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying out some tutorials about pygame and I'm now working on the Snowflake animation.

It's asking me to change the drawing movement code inside the for loop to take account of a new snow flakes data structure. But when i tried doing it it gave me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Uni/Sem/pyfiles/animating_snow.py", line 36, in <module>
    snow_list.append((WHITE[x, y]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Another thing the i need to do is to make it more animated. The instructions is to make the animation more animated, we can change the color of the snowflakes every so often. Every 5ht iteration of the while loop, we can update the color of each snowflake to a new randomly, color. "

for my solution... I have used the map function to do this. (it is required to use it.) I wrote a function that takes a single snowflake as its argument and returns a new snowflake with the same coordinates and a new, randomly chosen color. Then I added an  count variable to the program (as it is asked for us to use it).

This is my code for everything:

```
# Import libraries 'pygame' and 'random'
import pygame
import random

# Initialize the game engine
pygame.init()

BLACK = [0, 0, 0]
WHITE = [255, 255, 255]
GREEN = [0, 255, 0]
RED = [255, 0, 0]
colourList = [BLACK, WHITE, GREEN, RED]
color = random.choice(colourList)

# Set the height and width of the screen
SIZE = [400, 400]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snow Animation")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Create an empty list
snow_list = []

# Loop 100 times and add a snow flake in a random x,y position
for i in range(3):
    x = random.randrange(0, 400)
    y = random.randrange(0, 400)
    snow_list.append((WHITE[x, y]))


def recolour_snowflakes(snowflake):
    colour = random.choice(colourList)
    return colour, snowflake[1]


def animate_snowflake(snowflake):
    x = snowflake[1]
    y = snowflake[1]
    y += random.randrange(1, 3)
    if y > 400:
        x, y = (random.randrange(0, 400), random.randrange(-50, -10))
    return snowflake[0], [x, y]


count = 0
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    # change the color of snow flakes

    if count == 0:
        snow_list = list(map(recolour_snowflakes, snow_list))
        count = 0
    count += 1

    # process each snowflakes in the list
    snow_list = list(map(animate_snowflake, snow_list))

    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Process each snow flake in the list
    for i in range(len(snow_list)):

        # Draw the snow flake
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, snow_list[i][2])

        # Move the snow flake down one pixel
        snow_list[i][1] += 1

        # If the snow flake has moved off the bottom of the screen
        if snow_list[i][1] > 400:
            # Reset it just above the top
            y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
            snow_list[i][1] = y
            # Give it a new x position
            x = random.randrange(0, 400)
            snow_list[i][0] = x

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)

# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang' on exit.
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- When the flake is drawn, each flake is [color, [x, y]], so the x coordinate is `snow_list[i][1][0]`
- Drawing the circle requires a radius argument
- Fill the screen with gray so you can see the blank flakes
- `color` never changes so use `snow_list[i][0]` for the flake color

Here is the updated code:

```
# Import libraries 'pygame' and 'random'
import pygame
import random

# Initialize the game engine
pygame.init()

BLACK = [0, 0, 0]
WHITE = [255, 255, 255]
GREEN = [0, 255, 0]
RED = [255, 0, 0]
colourList = [BLACK, WHITE, GREEN, RED]
color = random.choice(colourList)

# Set the height and width of the screen
SIZE = [400, 400]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snow Animation")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Create an empty list
snow_list = []

# Loop 100 times and add a snow flake in a random x,y position
for i in range(30):
    x = random.randrange(0, 400)
    y = random.randrange(0, 400)
    snow_list.append([x, y])


def recolour_snowflakes(snowflake):
    colour = random.choice(colourList)
    return colour, snowflake


def animate_snowflake(snowflake):
    x = snowflake[1][0]
    y = snowflake[1][1]
    y += random.randrange(1, 3)
    if y > 400:
        x, y = (random.randrange(0, 400), random.randrange(-50, -10))
    return snowflake[0], [x, y]


count = 0
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    # change the color of snow flakes

    if count == 0:
        snow_list = list(map(recolour_snowflakes, snow_list))
    count += 1

    # process each snowflakes in the list
    snow_list = list(map(animate_snowflake, snow_list))

    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill((100,100,100))

    # Process each snow flake in the list
    for i in range(len(snow_list)):

        # Draw the snow flake
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, snow_list[i][0], snow_list[i][1], 10)

        # Move the snow flake down one pixel
        snow_list[i][1][0] += 1

        # If the snow flake has moved off the bottom of the screen
        if snow_list[i][1][0] > 400:
            # Reset it just above the top
            y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
            snow_list[i][1][1] = y
            # Give it a new x position
            x = random.randrange(0, 400)
            snow_list[i][1][0] = x

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)

# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang' on exit.
pygame.quit()
```